# setAcceptsTouchEvents only works fine after a gesture on trackpad

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, trackpad

I'm trying to use `setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES` to recognise custom touch events on the trackpad. Simply touching the trackpad nothing happens on the `touchesBeganWithEvent`. But if I do a gesture on the trackpad like pinching or scrolling the `touchesBeganWithEvent` starts to work properly. After one of that gestures, even if I simply touch the trackpad the `touchesBeganWithEvent` works. But I need to use `touchesBeganWithEvent` with simple touches without need to do a gesture before. The way it is seems like I have to do a gesture to initialize the `setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES`. What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: The `setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES` is in `initWithFrame`, and I can see that it is executed when the application starts.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that this problem disappears after reboot the macOS, or after just logout and login again. I tried to do anything else that could make the problem stop, like close all the applications in the macbook, switch desktops, put the OS in standby and then came back, but the only thing that makes the problem go away is to logoff or reboot the OS.

So, when the problem is gone I start my app and simply touching the trackpad the touchesBeganWithEvent is dispatched. Then after some hours the problem appears again, and touchesBeganWithEvent no more works until I do a gesture like pinching or scrolling. If I close my app and start again I need to do the gesture again.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I got same problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/touchesCancelledWithEvent%3a):

> The event will be sent to the view under the touch in the key window.
>   To get the set of touches that began for this view (or descendants of
>   this view) send [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseBegan
>   inView:self].

Some thoughts:

1. Make sure there is no descendant view that is intercepting the touch event.
2. Try programmatically making your window the key window before performing the touch event and see if this makes touchesBeganWithEvent be called.

Comment: Neither of these seems to help. Create a sub-class of `NSView`, set it up to receive touch events, add it to a window: that's enough to exhibit the asker's problem. Making the view key doesn't seem to help. :\